# Run command in each sub directory using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I want to run `mvn clean compile` in each directory in my Eclipse workspace containing a `pom.xml` file.

I was able to run `svn update` for each directory containing `.svn` like this:

```
PS C:\workspace> Get-ChildItem -recurse -force | 
where {$_.name -eq ".svn"} | 
foreach {svn update $_.parent.FullName}
```

However, this gives the full path to `svn` and runs from the current directory. The `mvn clean compile` needs to be run inside the directory, afaik. Tried doing the following, but then I just get an error saying something can't be null. Seems to be the first `cd` call it complains about. Do I just have some syntax wrong, or am I using `foreach` wrong?

```
PS C:\workspace> Get-ChildItem -recurse | 
where {$_.name -eq "pom.xml"} | 
foreach { cd $_.parent.name; mvn clean compile; cd ..; }
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Seems like `$_.parent.FullName` property worked in the first case because I was filtering out only directories. In this case I filtered out files, so I got it working by using `$_.DirectoryName` instead.

```
PS C:\workspace> Get-ChildItem -recurse | 
where {$_.name -eq "pom.xml"} | 
foreach { cd $_.DirectoryName; mvn clean compile; cd ..; }
```

Comment: First off, you should mark your answer as accepted. Second, how would I do this if I have lots of directories but each one of them has a directory of the svn structure branches, trunk, etc. and I want to cd into that trunk folder, and then into another folder inside called something like `toplevel-trunk` and then run mvn clean package?

Comment: Clean and Clear. :)

Answer (score 0):

- Create a batch file in the parent directory called 'foreach.bat'.
- Edit the file in a text editor (i.e. Notepad).
- Add this to the file:

  powershell.exe -Command "Get-ChildItem -recurse
  | where {$*.name -eq 'pom.xml'} | foreach { cd $*.DirectoryName; mvn
  clean compile; cd ..; }"
- Save and close the file.
- Run the file, eg. by double-clicking it.